# How to Get "Click URL" as a Google Tag Manager Trigger List Item

Tags: url, triggers, tags, click, google-tag-manager

I am following a number of tutorials to create a GTM tag as an event click.

In part of the final setup process, I need to create a trigger for event clicks.

All the tutorials I am seeing show that I should be able to select `Click URL` in the dropdown list, yet in my browser it does not exist. See screen shot below.

[image]

How can I get GTM to give me the **Click URL** option in the selection list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled Click URL (and other useful) variables:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @nyuen. I'll set that and post back later.

Comment: We need to get that on-topic/off-topic stuff sorted out some day. I agree it would be hugely annoying if those questions couldn't be answered here, but as is stands this is probably off-topic since it's about a configuration issue.

Comment: Excellent @nyuen. That was the answer.